# Paginar resultado de un formulario POST en Django

Tags: python, django

Buenas, llevo bastante tiempo buscando una solución óptima para paginar una lista de coches resultado de una búsqueda a través de un formulario POST.

Encontré la solución añadiendo esa lista de coches a request.session pero esa solución es ineficiente y muy lenta, tarda unos 5-8 segundos en guardar la lista en session ya que hay 80.000 coches en la base de datos.

Mi view.py

```
def buscar_coche_avanzado(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    coches = []
    form = BuscaAvanzadaCocheForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        marca = form.cleaned_data['marca']
        precioDesde = form.cleaned_data['precioDesde']
        precioHasta = form.cleaned_data['precioHasta']
        kmsDesde = form.cleaned_data['kmsDesde']
        kmsHasta = form.cleaned_data['kmsHasta']
        anioDesde = form.cleaned_data['anioDesde']
        anioHasta = form.cleaned_data['anioHasta']
        combustible = form.cleaned_data['combustible']
        publicista = form.cleaned_data['publicista']
        provincia =form.cleaned_data['provincia']
        cambio = form.cleaned_data['cambio']
        modelo = form.cleaned_data['modelo']
        marca = form.cleaned_data['marca']

        q=[]
        if marca:
            q.append(Q(marca=marca))
        if precioDesde and not precioHasta:
            q.append(Q(precio__gte=precioDesde))
        if precioHasta and not precioDesde:
            q.append(Q(precio__lte=precioHasta))
        if precioDesde and precioHasta:
            q.append(Q(precio__range=[precioDesde,precioHasta]))
        if kmsDesde and not kmsHasta:
            q.append(Q(kms__gte=kmsDesde))
        if kmsHasta and not kmsDesde:
            q.append(Q(kms__lte=kmsHasta))
        if kmsHasta and kmsDesde:     
            q.append(Q(kms__range=[kmsDesde,kmsHasta]))   
        if anioDesde and not anioHasta:
            q.append(Q(anio__gte=anioDesde))
        if anioHasta and not anioDesde:
            q.append(Q(anio__lte=anioHasta))
        if anioHasta and anioDesde: 
            q.append(Q(anio__range=[anioHasta,anioDesde]))
        if combustible:
            q.append(Q(tipo_combustible=combustible))
        if publicista:
            q.append(Q(tipo_publicista=publicista))
        if provincia: 
            q.append(Q(provincia=provincia))
        if cambio:
            q.append(Q(tipo_cambio=cambio))
        if modelo:
            q.append(Q(modelo__icontains=modelo))

        q_objects = Q() 
        for t in q:
            q_objects &= Q(t) 

        coches = Coche.objects.filter(q_objects) 

        paginator = Paginator(coches, 21) 
        page = request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            coches = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # Si la página no es un integer devuelve la primera página
            coches = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # Si la página está fuera de rango devuelve la última página
            coches = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)  

        return render(request,'lista_coches.html', {'coches':coches, 'BuscaAvanzadaCocheForm':BuscaAvanzadaCocheForm(),'marcas':Marca.objects.all(), 'BuscaCocheForm':BuscaCocheForm()})     

return redirect('lista_coches.html')
```

¿Cómo podría paginar la lista coches? En la plantilla, cuando le doy a siguiente evidentemente no pagina porque no entra por `if request.method == 'POST':` y para paginar necesito el resultado de la búsqueda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes, para mantener el formulario, guardar los datos en la sesión, pero cuando guardas los datos no me refiero a guardar los coches, si no, a guardar los datos de tu formulario en la sesión, con el objetivo de que sin necesidad de hacer el POST puedas recuperarlos en la siguiente página:

```
...
# cambiarías
if request.POST or request.session.get('initial_for_form', None) is not None:
    if request.POST:
        data = request.POST
    else:
        data = request.session.get('initial_for_form')

    form = BuscaAvanzadaCocheForm(data=data)
    if form.is_valid():
        marca = form.cleaned_data['marca']
        precioDesde = form.cleaned_data['precioDesde']
        precioHasta = form.cleaned_data['precioHasta']
        kmsDesde = form.cleaned_data['kmsDesde']
        kmsHasta = form.cleaned_data['kmsHasta']
        anioDesde = form.cleaned_data['anioDesde']
        anioHasta = form.cleaned_data['anioHasta']
        combustible = form.cleaned_data['combustible']
        publicista = form.cleaned_data['publicista']
        provincia =form.cleaned_data['provincia']
        cambio = form.cleaned_data['cambio']
        modelo = form.cleaned_data['modelo']
        marca = form.cleaned_data['marca']

        q = Q()
        if marca:
            q &= (Q(marca=marca))
        if precioDesde and not precioHasta:
            q &= (Q(precio__gte=precioDesde))
        if precioHasta and not precioDesde:
            q &= (Q(precio__lte=precioHasta))
        if precioDesde and precioHasta:
            q &= (Q(precio__range=[precioDesde,precioHasta]))
        if kmsDesde and not kmsHasta:
            q &= (Q(kms__gte=kmsDesde))
        if kmsHasta and not kmsDesde:
            q &= (Q(kms__lte=kmsHasta))
        if kmsHasta and kmsDesde:     
            q &= (Q(kms__range=[kmsDesde,kmsHasta]))   
        if anioDesde and not anioHasta:
            q &= (Q(anio__gte=anioDesde))
        if anioHasta and not anioDesde:
            q &= (Q(anio__lte=anioHasta))
        if anioHasta and anioDesde: 
            q &= (Q(anio__range=[anioHasta,anioDesde]))
        if combustible:
            q &= (Q(tipo_combustible=combustible))
        if publicista:
            q &= Q(tipo_publicista=publicista))
        if provincia: 
            q &= (Q(provincia=provincia))
        if cambio:
            q &= (Q(tipo_cambio=cambio))
        if modelo:
            q &= (Q(modelo__icontains=modelo))

        q_objects = q

        coches = Coche.objects.filter(q_objects) 

        paginator = Paginator(coches, 21) 
        page = request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            coches = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # Si la página no es un integer devuelve la primera página
            coches = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # Si la página está fuera de rango devuelve la última página
            coches = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        # escribes la sesion con los datos del formulario
        request.session['initial_for_form'] = form.cleaned_data

        return render(request,'lista_coches.html', {'coches':coches, 'BuscaAvanzadaCocheForm':BuscaAvanzadaCocheForm(),'marcas':Marca.objects.all(), 'BuscaCocheForm':BuscaCocheForm()})     

return redirect('lista_coches.html')
```

Otra forma, es poder pasar todos los datos a partir de la url y recogerla con el GET, pero es un proceso más largo, y quedaria una url muy larga, aunque es la forma como se hace usualmente, un ejemplo que puedes ver es en mismo administrador de django, que al momento de usar un filtro, cambian los parametros de la url de acuerdo al filtro que usaste

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, tanto por la rapidez de respuesta como por el código, funciona a la perfección! 
¡Feliz año nuevo!